# Is this the most accepted definition of knowledge today?

Tags: knowledge

I found this Euler diagram representing a definition of knowledge problematic.

First, propositions should only express beliefs. When there is no belief, there should be no proposition. But the diagram shows that some propositions are not beliefs.

Secondly, there should be pre-verbal beliefs that have not been expressed in propositions, but the diagram shows that all beliefs are propositions.

Finally, truth should be a property of beliefs. There should be no truth independent of beliefs, but the diagram shows that some truths are not beliefs.

The source of this diagram is [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology). I wonder how widely accepted this definition is.

[image]

Comment: What this presents is a classical JTB ("justified true belief") account of knowledge. Contemporary accounts have to deal with Gettier-style edge cases too...

Comment: I would say that all Truths must be beliefs, and that the area labelled Propositions should simply be unlabeled, as "unknown", not considered yet, as if outside the light-cone of the flow of awareness. I would also divide belief into conscious (thought of, reasoned about), and unconscious (not consciously examined), like when I push a door but should have pulled it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as Joseph Weissman pointed out, since Gettier pointed out a significant [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem) with this definition several new definitions were proposed. The case is not closed yet as it seems that every new definition has some quirky consequences or can still be gettierized.

Addressing you questions:

1. There are some propositions no-one believes. Some of them because they are plainly wrong, some of them because no-one ever came up with them like 16783-465²*12.85/log(2)=100.12345. It's not only wrong, I'd think it's something no-one ever thought to be true - it was never a belief.
2. The word 'belief' here is somewhat of a technical term: Only propositional structured things can be beliefs, because the entity needed needs the ability to have a truth value assigned to it. If you are very convinced of something, but fail to express *it* this '*it*' is the thing we need: The proposition, which can be true or false.
3. Truth is a property of beliefs. But also of propositions. And some of them happen to be true without any-one believing it. For example: Do you think the number of hairs on your head: are the odd or even? One of the both is true, and has been true even before you thought about it.

Comment: Thanks, @Einer. I read in some other other context that propositions are incomplete symbols. Until they are asserted or appear in other asserted propositions, they have no meanings by themselves. I confess I don't quite understand it. I only remembered it as rule.

Comment: @GeorgeChen It kinda depends on who you are asking, but beginning with Frege it's somewhat common to assume, that proposition indeed don't _have_ a meaning; they _are_ the meaning (or way more precisely: the sense ;-))

Comment: According to this theory(1st ED of W&R's Principia Mathematica), judgement is a part of proposition, and the phrase expressing a proposition is an incomplete symbol. The explanation smacks of sense-data which Russell later abandoned.

Comment: Re: your point 3: There is no truth until someone frames a question (proposition). Truth is something that humans consider, it is in their minds. Outside the mind, things simply ARE, there is no "thing that is not", so there is no "untruth" outside of our thoughts. Perhaps this is the OP's line of inquiry?

Answer (score 2):

Your question includes some mistakes.

You write:

> First, propositions should only express beliefs. When there is no belief, there should be no proposition. But the diagram shows that some propositions are not beliefs.

This is wrong. It is common to put a whole load of facts into a computer program and to let it work out many complicated implications of those facts that people want to use but not to work out. Indeed, the person might not even want to know those implications. He might design another program to take the output of the first program and follow a routine for fixing the problem without him ever knowing the specifics of the problem. Also a lot of stuff in books isn't believed by anyone because the point of writing it down in a book is so that people don't have to remember it.

> Finally, truth should be a property of beliefs. There should be no truth independent of beliefs, but the diagram shows that some truths are not beliefs.

So the world didn't exist before there were people around to know about it. Dinosaurs didn't exist.

The wikipedia diagram is wrong, but so are you. As others have commented it seems to represent the idea that knowledge is justified true belief. I have already explained that knowledge need not be belief.

As Popper pointed out in Chapter I of "Realism and the Aim of Science" justification is impossible, unnecessary and undesirable. If you assess ideas using argument then the arguments have premises and rules of inference and the result of the argument may not be true (or probably true) if the premises and rules of inference are false. You might try to solve this by coming up with a new argument that proves the premises and rules of inference but then you have the same problem with those premises and rules of inference.

It is perfectly possible for an idea to solve some problem and so to constitute knowledge without it being true, so knowledge need not be true either. Knowledge is not justified true belief.

Comment: Regarding the second mistake, there are facts before there were people. Truths are not the same as facts.

Comment: I need some time to think what a proposition is. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Originally, belief is defined as a state of organism. Whether rocks and chairs have beliefs is unknown. Now we can say computers definitely have beliefs, because its internal state changes according to some external facts.

Comment: A book doesn't change its state.

Comment: All beliefs are private. What is public or what's in the book are indices at best. "Blue mixed with yellow makes green" is only a verbal habit for those who have never seen blue and yellow. Propositions in books have no meanings before someone reads them.

Comment: Propositions in a book are not different from those uttered by a person. Both express beliefs. Shakespeare wrote a lot of proposition that even he himself did not believe. In this case, we define beliefs as mental states, and imaginations are definitely mental states.

Comment: At this point, I think mental state is better than belief. All propositions express mental states.

Comment: Shakespeare's propositions are never asserted; they are not nonsense either. I need some more time to think about this.

Comment: Shakespeare's eternal lines are not propositions, because there are no judgement involved.

Comment: Books of logarithms and values of Bessel functions express beliefs?

Comment: You know what that picture says? It says in the beginning was the word.

Comment: Not really. It says very clearly that not all propositions are necessarily believed even if they are true. You stepped forward with your idea of "propositions express mental states", you could of made it better by saying "possible mental states", but instead you went backwards so fast that you tripped and fell into nonsense.

Comment: Knowledge and beliefs are experiences that humans have when they think about something. They do not "exist" as such. Knowledge is that which corresponds with reality, belief is something which might be knowledge, or might be a false belief. Truth is something that we think about, because we can consider something without sufficient evidence, but in the hope of gathering the evidence. If we don't think, something is neither true, nor is it false, like how if a tree falls in the forest and no one hears it, it neither makes a sound, nor does not, because the listener is not there.

Comment: Knowledge is not experience for reasons explained above. And if truth is correspondence to reality, then something need not be a belief to be true, e.g. - a computer program can correctly answer some question about the Bessel functions without knowing how. Also, there is no such thing as sufficient evidence. Knowledge is either right or wrong. Evidence can't prove it right for several reasons, e.g. - if the knowledge is explanatory it typically covers many cases that cannot be checked such as past events that left no evidence. See "Objective Knowledge", Chapter 1 by Popper.